# how to insert multiple checkbox values into database?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, semantic-ui

So, I have a form in that i have two check boxes and both can be checked but when i check both the data is not going into database only the first value is inserting.

I tried using getParameterValues, also gave it as an array in bean and also tried some jquery functions but not able to achieve this can some one please help ??

I know there are already many examples out here but none of them worked for me.

I'll add my code below.

This is the controller servlet

```
    public void insertProduct(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws SQLException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, ServletException, ParseException
    {       
        String code = request.getParameter("code");        
        String name = request.getParameter("name"); 
        int price = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("price"));
        String home_main_category = request.getParameter("home_main_category");
        String home_sub_category = request.getParameter("home_sub_category");
        String p_avail = request.getParameter("p_avail");
        String p_act = request.getParameter("p_act");      // This is the checkbox
        String pro_exp_date = request.getParameter("pro_exp_date");
        String pro_manufacture_date = request.getParameter("pro_manufacture_date");
         
        Product newProduct = new Product(code,name,price,home_main_category,home_sub_category,p_avail,p_act,pro_exp_date,pro_manufacture_date);
        
        try 
        {
            productDAO.insertProduct(newProduct);
        }
        
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("CreateProduct.jsp");
        
        rd.forward(request,response);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, the problem is with duplicated name in form - `p_act`:

```html
 <input type = "checkbox" name = "p_act" value = "In_Stock" >
 <input type = "checkbox" name = "p_act" value = "Out_Of_Stock" >
```

I think you should do separate names for each position (like `p_act1`, `p_act2`) and concat them somehow. For example:

```java
String p_act = Stream.of(request.getParameter("p_act1"), request.getParameter("p_act2"))
   .filter(Objects::nonNull)
   .collect(Collectors.joining(","))
```

Comment: thank you for replying !!
when i tried like this  String p_act = Stream.of(request.getParameter("p_act1"),request.getParameter("p_act2")).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
 its showing two errors 
1.) (Objects::nonNull) => Objects cannot be resolved.
2.) (Collectors.joining(",") => Collectors cannot be resolved.

can you please guide how to resolve this??
i am new to jsp and servlets.

Comment: You probably using older version of JDK, or have incorrect imports.
But it's just example how to concat 2 strings to 1. You can use other way, like:
```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
if (request.getParameter("p_act1") != null) {
    items.add(request.getParameter("p_act1"));
}
if (request.getParameter("p_act2") != null) {
    items.add(request.getParameter("p_act2"));
}
String p_act = String.join(",", items);
```

Comment: worked like a charm !!
thanks a ton !! you solved a major problem of mine. really appreciate the effort you put in to solve the problem.